# Entity framework Code First: what to do when Migrations are not enough?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

It happens only when I'm *playing*, until now, but I was wondering what are the correct strategies to use when Migrations give some error.

I don't have a specific example right now, but it happens that, specially when making large updates to the database, add-migration command gives some kind of error, saying that it cannot create the migration.

So I tried to use a Database First strategy on the existing database, but the generated classes are *totally* different from my originals, so it looks like it's not feasable to start with a Code First approach, and LATER switch to a Database First approach.

So my ultimate question is: are we all sure that Code First schemas are *always* in some way updatable, or do we have to worry about a *possible* black hole???

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you describe a development issue, that not exactly affects your clients. It's not that the migration fails when you deploy it, rather, you are unable to add it to the project.

This sounds like a minor issue. Just do whatever possible to resolve the issue and regain the possibility to create new migrations. Do not switch to other design strategies just because your Visual Studio encounters some problems. It's like the issue with specific tool alters the whole architecture of your application.

If you need further assistance, include more details on your model classes and the actual error message. Also, make sure that the issue is objective, i.e. is not specific to a single development machine.

Comment: My question is a little different: right now, I could generate all the needed migrations for my *actual* projects, so I have not problems to resolve... My question is more theoretical: can we *trust* that migrations are *always* generatable, or there are limits in what changes we can do to tables, relations, and so on? Is there anyone that *knows* it? Anyway, thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Migrations automatically include some model changes (new tables, new columns, new relations) and you can manually alter migrations to contain any transact SQL statements as well as any C# code. In practice, I can't think of any limits.

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't think about this in these terms, but now this is even more scaring! :-) What happens after I write a manual update like this, with SQL statements? What chances do I have to generate the next migration, then?

Comment: 100% if you don't mess with the database.

Comment: I like when people are so confident! :-) It's better if we can touch a real problem: when I can recreate some border situation I'll let you know! Thanks a lot, for now...

Comment: I think you exaggerate the issue. Migration generaiton is very simple, it just scans the database's metadata (tables, columns, relations) and generates some code. Sure, there are probably some not-so-well tested border cases where something could go wrong but the probability of an issue there is the same as the probability of some issues anywhere else in the base class library. The idea to come back with some concrete issues sounds like a good one, then.